# InDesign, How to email video

Tags: adobe-indesign

I placed a video as an F4V in my InDesign document, saved it as an interactive PDF and emailed it.  When I send it to myself, download it and open it, it opens in Adobe Reader and plays just fine. If I just click on "View"  I see the image but it does not play.  When I email it to my client he tells me it is not there at all. not even the image, let alone one that plays  Other interactive elements work just fine, like links to his website or Face Book.

I am new to this and he is my first client.  Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Thank you so much,   Linda Lamme

Answer (score 2):

F4V is not a supported video format in InDesign.

You can work with the following movie formats:

- AVI
- MPEG
- SWF
- Quicktime (Version 6.0 or above required)

Also, be sure you embed the video into the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to embed the file in the document before saving it as a .pdf

It could also be that your client doesn't have a pdf reader that will play flash video.